# checkbox array not working

Tags: php, arrays, forms

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='product[]' value='$counter'>
```

for some reason, when I run the form with this name for this input, it won't run the PHP script, it won't even run the beginning of the script.

Is there some reason this isn't working? am I doing it wrong? I thought this is the actual way this would work.

[Edit]
this is the actual full script in the form:

```
foreach($producten as $row)
{
    echo("
    <label class='mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect' for='checkbox-" . $counter ."'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='product[]' value='$counter'>
    <span class='mdl-checkbox__label'>" . $row['productcode'] . ' ' . $row['categorie'] . ' ' . $row['merk'] . ' ' . $row['type'] . ' ' . $row['cpu'] . ' ' . $row['ram'] . ' ' . $row['os'] . ' ' . $row['hdd'] . ' ' ."</span>
    </label>
    ");
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP script please?

Comment: use `$counter` inside php tag

Comment: `echo("meep");
    if(isset($_POST['leerlingnr']) && isset($_POST["inleverdatum"]) && isset($_POST['product']))
    {` is the beginning of the script, though as I stated, it won't even echo "meep".

Comment: @Saty what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: It's incomplete code, is it like :  <?php echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='product[]' value='$counter'>"; ?>

Comment: use it as `value='<?php echo $counter;?>'`

Comment: edited the code, sorry, forgot to add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image].
I have checked with below code as related your code. It's working with Checkbox array. I hope it's will help you. All the best.

```
 <form action="#" method="POST">
    <?php
    $producten = array('1a','2b','3c','4d');
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($producten as $row)
    {
        echo("
        <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='product[]' value='$row'> <label class='mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect' for='checkbox-" . $counter ."'> $row </label><br>
        ");
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

Output:

```
Array
```

(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1a
            [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyzAL.png) => 2b
            [2] => 3c
            [3] => 4d
        )
)